# Use dlib's `find_max_global` in python, with changing number of parameters

Tags: python, optimization, dlib

Dlib has recently released a new method for global optimization, minimizing the number of function calls (http://blog.dlib.net/2017/12/a-global-optimization-algorithm-worth.html)

I would like to use this in Python, and for a simple cost function it works well:

```
import dlib
import numpy as np

def cost_fn_2_params(x0, x1):
    return np.sum([x0, x1])

dlib.find_max_global(f=cost_fn_2_params, bound1=[-1., -1], 
                     bound2=[1., 1], num_function_calls=10)
```

Now, in my particular use-case I have a variable number of parameters going in to my cost function, and `find_global_max` expects the cost function to have a static number of arguments. For example, defining the cost function in another way:

```
def cost_fn_unspecified_params(**params):
    return np.sum(params)

dlib.find_max_global(f=cost_fn_unspecified_params, bound1=[-1., -1], 
                     bound2=[1., 1], num_function_calls=10)
```

I get the following error:

```
Failing expression was num == args.size().
The function being optimized takes a number of arguments that doesn't agree with the size of the bounds lists you provided to find_max_global()
```

My question is: Is there any way to dynamically define functions with a certain number of arguments? Excluding the `*params` syntax as this apparently looks like a single argument to `dlib`.

I have considered using `exec` to define a function, but it seems overly complicated. This is my best solution so far:

```
def get_fn_n_arguments(n):
    argument_list = [f'x{ii}' for ii in range(n)]
    argument_str = ','.join(argument_list)
    def_str = f'def fn({argument_str}): \n\tparams = [{argument_str}]\n\treturn cost_fn_unspecified_params(params)'
    print(def_str)
    exec(def_str, globals())
```

This puts a function `fn` into the global namespace, and now I can do

```
get_fn_n_arguments(2)
dlib.find_max_global(f=fn, bound1=[-1., -1], 
                     bound2=[1., 1], num_function_calls=10)
```

It works, but it seems like a very brittle solutions. I would really like to improve it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I ended up not using dlib after all, but it seems dlib 19.10 fixes this problem.

From http://dlib.net/release_notes.html :

 Added support for variadic Python functions in find_max_global().

Comment: Many thanks, I'll see if I can get a conda version.

Comment: Out of interest, what optimiser did you end up using if not dlib?

Comment: @MattWenham I used LMFIT - https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/